Add new disk partition as first
I have a 1000GB disk (/dev/sbd) containing 1 single partition (/dev/sbd1) which is 60% full.
I would like to create a new small partition (some GB) before this one. So, the old partition would become /dev/sbd2, and a new partition /dev/sdb1 would appear before it.
Can I do this without deleting current disk data?
Partitions table is msdos. Partitions are ext4.

Not easily, because partition/file system tables are at the beginning. You'd need to move the current partition up, then add the new one.

Ok, that way I can create a new partition /dev/sda2 before /dev/sda1. Any way to reorder partitions?

@luca.vercelli I understand your issue, You cannot copy the /dev/sdb1 to a new /dev/sdb2 because it's 60% fully capacity, Which means that you cannot create another partition /dev/sdb2 same as that one (with 600MB) . and delete the previous one and create a new one which is the small partition, So you just want to move it, But unfortunately as @DrMoishe Pippik said it's not easily achieved, and either or either you need to backup the data somewhere in case the operation fails, So i would recommand using a external storage device to do so and delete the old one.


So, the old partition would become /dev/sbd2, and a new partition /dev/sdb1 would appear before it. Can I do this without deleting current disk data?

If the partition numbers are all you care about, that is totally doable. You simply recreate the partition table / entries:
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,UUID /dev/sda
NAME    SIZE FSTYPE UUID
sda    29.1G        
├─sda1  512M vfat   C766-BA48
└─sda2 28.6G btrfs  4fb525df-1f32-48da-933b-2b54ce96c991
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 61069312 sectors, 29.1 GiB
Model: MassStorageClass
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 9F0A8E08-E6EC-4A7E-8A7E-E0E871CE36D8
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 61069278
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 22461 sectors (11.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1           16384         1064959   512.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   2         1064960        61063167   28.6 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem

Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): y

Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (34-61069278, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 1064960
Last sector (1064960-61069278, default = 61067263) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 61063167
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'

Command (? for help): n
Partition number (2-128, default 2): 
First sector (34-61069278, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 16384
Last sector (16384-1064959, default = 1064959) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 1064959
Current type is 8300 (Linux filesystem)
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): 
Changed type of partition to 'Linux filesystem'

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 61069312 sectors, 29.1 GiB
Model: MassStorageClass
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 449A96E3-10D1-43F0-8E7F-164FA6C7E42D
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 61069278
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 22461 sectors (11.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1         1064960        61063167   28.6 GiB    8300  Linux filesystem
   2           16384         1064959   512.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sda.
The operation has completed successfully.
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,UUID /dev/sda
NAME    SIZE FSTYPE UUID
sda    29.1G        
├─sda1 28.6G btrfs  4fb525df-1f32-48da-933b-2b54ce96c991
└─sda2  512M vfat   C766-BA48

(gdisk itself actually has an advanced command that allows you to "transpose" partition entries. I am doing / showing the above just because it does not support msdos partition table and fdisk does not seem to have equivalent command.)
You need to be really careful though. While gdisk is decent enough that it would touch only the partition table / entries, other utilities might wipe the filesystem signatures, with or without prompting you for confirmation.
Also you'll need to make sure the coverage (start/end) of the new partition entries are exactly the same as the old ones. If there are Windows partitions, also make sure their partition type code / GUID is correct.
And note that by recreating the partitions, the PARTUUIDs (not filesystem UUIDs though) would be changed. (PARTUUID isn't a real thing in msdos partition table, IIRC. It has only a "disk identifier", which is used to form "fake" PARTUUIDs in Linux. If you delete the partition entries one by one, the "disk identifier" would not change.)
I am not sure if there are any potential but real caveats in having "out-of-order" partition entries, but I have seen enough unintentional cases, and I never heard of any case that it is actually problematic.

Some more background information: by definition partitions are really just metadata / record entries that are essentially ranges of contiguous logical blocks (sometimes aka sectors). The actual data (such as filesystems) on the logical blocks (referred / "covered" by the partition entries) won't go away when you delete only the partition table / entries. (Only the logical blocks used by the partition table / entries themselves would be rewritten / wiped. FYI, only the first logical block, a.k.a. LBA 0, is used by msdos partition table if it has only primary partitions.)
Therefore, once you recreate partition entries with the same coverage, you can access the data "directly" (as in, through the partition device nodes) again, as long as the utility you used to delete the old entries hasn't done more than it should.
In Linux, the trailing number of the partition device nodes (e.g. 1 in /dev/sda1) refers to which "slot" in the partition table the corresponding partition entries resides. The slot number does not necessarily reflect which range of logical blocks a partition entry covers, as in, sda1 does not necessarily means the range it covers is the first range on sda LBA-wise.

Good idea! thank you!

You can boot from a gparted ISO or USB stick.
First you need to shrink the 1st partition so there is room for #2.
Then select "resize/move" and use the mouse to move the partition forward.
Then you can create a partition in the gap you created.
Since your drive is 60% full this could take hours
The final step is to apply the changes and wait several hours for the changes to be made.
Note:  gparted will have to move ALL 600gb of data forward.

It'll move more than just 600 GB – resize uses filesystem-specific tools but move doesn't, so it won't skip the empty parts. So if the 1000 GB partition is shrunk to e.g. 990 GB, then the full 990 GB will need to be shifted. (One might shrink the partition to 600 GB instead, then grow it back after the move is done, but some filesystems might not like being shrunk to where they become 99.9% full...)

Yes, Resizing it to less than about 90% will cause the drive to do hundreds if not thousands of reallocations slowing the process down even more.  Shrinking to about 99% can add hours to the process, and is not a good thing for the filesystem.
